# Load Image using onClickListener

Tags: java, android, image

I have a class that I borrowed from [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-load-image-url-example) that loads and image from a URL. I am trying to use the class by calling it from a onClickListener (if that makes sense) But I am not sure how to call the class and show the results. Right now I am just working with a static URL but eventually I it will be dynamic.

OnclickListerner in MainActivity Java:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
        showImage go = new showImage();
    }

});
```

and this is my showImage class:

```
package com.flash_tattoo;

public class showImage extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);

        ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        String url = null;
        Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/android.png");
        imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exc="+e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to call a new layout and then attach my showImage object to it? Any help would be great. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point, Java naming conventions have class names capitalised, this allows anybody reading the code to instantly know what's what. Please rename the `showImage` class.

Secondly, this will cause a long running operation to happen in the UI thread, this is best done with an AsyncTask - see this article on [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) - or a new Thread with a Handler. Long running operations on the UI thread will block any input handler events from being processed in a timely fashion and could cause your application to become unresponsive, especially with a slow mobile connection. Consider adding a progress bar or some method of letting the user know that the application is still doing something while they wait.

To answer the original question, it looks like `showImage` is an `Activity`. This means that inside the listener you don't need to create a new `showImage` object, but rather fire off an `Intent` to view that `Activity`. Assuming you have the correct layout files I don't see anything that won't work here.

You also seem to have an unused variable, `String url = null;` is not needed.

Edit: You also shouldn't really be using `System.out.println()`, although it will have the desired results. The standard method of logging in Android is to use the [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html) system.

As suri has mentioned, it's also not necessary to have an entire new `Activity` to show your image. If you move the `showImage` class functions into your first `Activity` and add an `ImageView` to the first layout, you can load the image in the same `Activity` as the button.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I will move my showImage class into the MainActivity and add my Image view. +1

Answer (score 1):

No need to call a new Layout you can put One button and a ImageView in a Layout and set the Image as you have done. Your code work's properly I have checked. Hope you might have given Permission in AndroidManifiest file.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions:
1) Create AsyncTask for downloading image;
2) Use callback for notifying of downloading result;
3) In callback set you image.

Please note, that if you want to set image not from UI thread you should use  runOnUiThread